# Mantener div oculto hasta que no pase por una altura fija (ni > ni < sino =)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Con el siguiente código mi Div aparece a partir de 1000px pero si lo hago desaparecer pasándole el puntero por encima a cualquier altura reaparece en cuanto el scroll avanza 1px y lo que quiero es que el div SOLO vuelva a aparecer cuando el scroll pasa por 1000px. Gracias.

```js
$(window).scroll(function()  {
 var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (y = 500 )  {
      $(".topmenu").fadeIn();   // > 100px from top - show div
    }
});


$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $(".outmouseover").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".outmouseover").fadeOut(0);
  });

});
```

```css
.youdiclass{position:fixed; display:none;width:100px; height:100px; background:red;}
#back{width:300px; height:500px;background:blue; margin:auto;}
.height600{}
.topmenu{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: rgba(255,246,0,1.00);
  z-index: 1;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topmenu outmouseover"></div>

<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
```

Comment: yo no entiendo jquery, pero creo que deberia de mirar esta linea if (y = 500 )  { | y usar algo similar a esto if (y == 500 )  { | puede tratar con esto if (y >= 1000 )  { pero usted dice que tiene que ser igual, pero imagino que el scroll puede dar por ejemplo 501 con lo cual no cumpliria , espero ayude

Comment: podira crea una variable que se active a true, cuando  if (y >= 1000 && variable == false) { variable = true ..// y en otra parte cuando el scroll este por debajo de 1000 que se cambie la variable a false Saludos

Comment: No he entendido nada la verdad... he probado solo (y==500) y no funciona. Pero gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es lo que queria decirle tomese como (pseudocode) pues no se de jQuery

```js
$(window).scroll(function()  {
 var y = $(window).scrollTop();


    if (y < 1000 ){
       variable = false;
    }

    if (y >= 1000 && variable == false){
      variable = true;

      $(".topmenu").fadeIn();   // > 100px from top - show div
    }

});

var variable = false;

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $(".outmouseover").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".outmouseover").fadeOut(0);
  });

});
```

```css
.youdiclass{position:fixed; display:none;width:100px; height:100px; background:red;}
#back{width:300px; height:500px;background:blue; margin:auto;}
.height600{}
.topmenu{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: rgba(255,246,0,1.00);
  z-index: 1;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topmenu outmouseover"></div>

<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
```

Nota: Si usted usa exactamente `y == 1000` y el scroll es 1001 no se cumple la condicion, entoces no se mostrara, si es eso lo que quiere solo tiene que poner `y == 1000 && variable == false`.

---

> gracias, funciona parcialmente porque pretendo que al subir hacia
>   y=1000 (al pasar por 1000) reaparezca el div. Puedes ayudarme con eso?

creo que esto le puede ayudar en lo que busca:

```js
var variable = false;
var s        = 1000;

$(window).scroll(function()  {
   
      var y = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (y >= s && variable == false){

         variable = true;
         $(".topmenu").fadeIn();   // > 100px from top - show div

      }else if (y < s && variable == true){

         variable = false;
         $(".topmenu").fadeIn();   // > 100px from top - show div

     }

});

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $(".outmouseover").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".outmouseover").fadeOut(0);
  });

});
```

```css
.youdiclass{position:fixed; display:none;width:100px; height:100px; background:red;}
#back{width:300px; height:500px;background:blue; margin:auto;}
.height600{}
.topmenu{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: rgba(255,246,0,1.00);
  z-index: 1;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topmenu outmouseover"></div>

<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
```

Nota: Puede que quiera refactorizarlo, pero lo puede tomar como base.

Comment: gracias, funciona parcialmente porque pretendo que al subir hacia y=1000 (al pasar por 1000) reaparezca el div. Puedes ayudarme con eso?

Comment: @IvanSoler le acabo de dejar un Update espero le ayude, por otro lado puede que sea mejor para futuras preguntas que detalle la idea en general y su comportamiento, pues creo que sera mejor para el que responda sepa todo lo que necesita, espero entienda y no se lo tome a mal Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias @AngelAngel y disculpa el error.

Comment: @IvanSoler no sin problema, una pregunta usted acepto la respuesta, porque vi que si pero estaba haciendo unas cosas y desaparecio el check y no se si usted lo retiro o es un bug, me puede decir. Saludos

Comment: Lo retiré sin querer. Solucionado. Gracias.

Comment: @IvanSoler gracias por responder es que lo vi, pero como estaba modificando algunas partes y luego desaparecio pense que era por el roll. De todas maneras no es obligatorio hacer check pero puede entender sus ventajas si lee esto http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Saludos